# Inferring mean(X/Y) from mean(X) and mean(Y)

Tags: error-propagation

X and Y are linked variables (i.e. they relate to different measurements in the same individuals), I know the value of mean(X) and of mean(Y) but I do not know the individual level values of X and Y.

I would like to infer the value of mean(X/Y), which I can see is not the same as mean(X)/mean(Y) (unless the correlation of X and Y is 1). I would also like to infer the value of SD(X/Y).

If I know the correlation of X and Y is there a way to infer these values?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $\mathbb E[X/Y]=\mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[1/Y]$. But no chance to know better if you only know $\mathbb E[X]$ and $\mathbb E[Y]$.

Comment: @Surb I think the suggestion is that $X$ and $Y$ are linked so unlikely to be independent

Comment: Thanks both X and Y are linked (they are measures in the same individual and have a correlation of around 0.8). Is there still no way to estimate [/] if we know this correlation and we know [] and [], from playing around with dummy data it feels as though there should be